# I am hoping someone can direct me, so I can learn proficiency in c

Tags: c

Here is the assignment: Modify the grade book code from Unit 3 so that it uses heap memory to store percentage grades in the range from 0 to 100 (inclusive). The program should allow the user to indicate when he or she is done entering grades (since the user may not have grades to fill the whole array). When the user is done entering grades, the program should print out the grades entered by the user. Be sure to free the heap memory before the program ends.

Here is my code so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0, j;
    int intArray [15];
    int gradeNum;
    int gradeEntered;
    int totalEntered;
    float gradeBook [20];
    char ans;
    char input [15];
    int* gradeNums;

    for(gradeNum = 0; gradeNum < 15; gradeNum++) {
        printf("You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for \"Done\".");
        printf("\nPlease enter grade -> \n");
        fgets(input, 15, stdin);

        if(strncmp(input,'D',1)== 0) {
            break;
        }

        gradeEntered = atoi(input);
        intArray[gradeNum]= gradeEntered;
        totalEntered++;
    }

    gradeNums = (int*) malloc (gradeBook * sizeof(int));

    printf("You have entered %d grades \n", gradeNum + 1);
    printf("The grades you have entered are:  \n");

    for (j=0; j <= i; j++) {
        printf("%.2f ", gradeBook[j]);
        printf("\n \n");
    }

    free(gradeNums);

    return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to get my gradeBook at the end to execute correctly with for (j=0; j<= i; j++) and I know I am missing several pieces to work together. Any assistance/resources are greatly appreciated.
The instructor is not very helpful.

Comment: `i` is equal to 0 and never changes, so what do you expect `for (j=0; j <= i; j++)` to do?

Comment: Yes maybe: ```j < totalEntered``` instead of ```j <= i```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is important to get as many support from your compiler as possible. Enable warnings. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra`. That should give you some hint that this is wrong: `strncmp(input,'D',1)`. This function compares strings. Not a string and an `int` value. You meant `"D"` instead of `'D'`. But for single characters you could just use `input[0]=='D'` for the same purpose.

Comment: interjay- my plan was to have a the program execute the grades like: The grades entered >- [1] 90, [2] 95, [3] 97, and so on, but I am not understanding what I am doing right or wrong.

Comment: We can help you with the program presented in the question, but requests for references to third-party resources, such as is expressed by this question's title, are off-topic here.

Comment: Take a look at [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) You don't learn to code watching videos ... it's the quite time with the book-in-lap, or reference-in-a-window reading where the bulk of learning takes place. Know what you need to do before you pickup the keyboard. The will save you no end of frustration.

Comment: Why `gradeNums = (int*) malloc (gradeBook * sizeof(int));` and why `gradeBook` instead of `gradeNum`? Also in C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @CJay Horton --Thank you so very much for the thorough explanation of each problem and breaking each down for me to have a better understanding of what I was overlooking. As you can imagine, I am getting bits and pieces from video instruction and the two books listed above. I do appreciate you taking the time to look at my code.   I will be making some adjustments so I can learn from what you provided. Thanks again from a fellow native Texan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer - my solutions below are done to help you get the immediate issues with your code to a point to where it will work and you can continue your learning path.  Please keep in mind that this code will NOT suffice in the real world, but since you are still in 'learning land' it will work for your needs, for now. Please read through comments made by users and take them into consideration as well. In addition, you are using library functions that have LOTS of caveats and pitfalls.  Once you understand the immediate mistakes of your current code, do some SO searches for these functions (fgets(), strncmp(), atoi(), and malloc()) to find more information on correctly using them.**

Your code has multiple syntax errors and logical/design issues.

`First lesson to learning 'C':  The compiler is your friend.`

The code you originally posted won't compile.  Let's see what our friend, the compiler, has to say...

```
error: missing terminating " character
   18 |     printf("You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for

error: missing terminating " character
   19 |     "Done".");
```

**Problems:**

- Do you see how it broke this into two error messages?  That means you have something wrong with your string.
- You need to escape the double quotes around Done.

**Solutions:**

- Remove the carriage return after 'for' or break it up into multiple strings like:

```
printf("string one "
"string two");
```

- Escape the double quotes -> \"Done\"

Okay, let's see what the compiler says now...

```
 warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strncmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   22 |  if(strncmp(input,'D',1)== 0)
      |     ^~~~~~~
```

**Problem:** This is telling us that we are using a function (strncmp) that we haven't declared yet.

**Solution:** Include the string header file at the top -> #Include <string.h>

Let's see what happens now...

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strncmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   23 |  if(strncmp(input,'D',1)== 0)
      |                   ^~~
      |                   |
      |                   int
```

**Problem:**  Here is the strncmp function signature:

```
int strncmp(const char *str1, const char *str2, size_t n)
```

The compiler is telling you that your second argument is an (int), but the function requires a pointer to a char.

**Solution:** Declare a char so you can pass a pointer to it

```
char done = 'D';
```

Now call strncmp like:

```
if(strncmp(input,&done,1)== 0)
```

Now, let's see what happens...

```
error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘float *’ and ‘long unsigned int’)
   36 |      gradeNums = (int*) malloc (gradeBook * sizeof(int));
      |                                 ~~~~~~~~~ ^
      |                                 |
      |                                 float *
```

**Problem:**  gradebook is an array of type float.  You are multiplying a pointer to float times an int (size_t) here.  You can't multiply pointers in C.  Even if gradeBook was a float, multiplying a float and an int would yield a float. malloc expects an int (size_t).

**Solution:** change gradeBook to totalEntered.

Now, we should be able to compile and run the program.

> It is wrong and won't output what you are expecting

Here is what we get...

```
You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for "Done".
Please enter grade ->
11
You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for "Done".
Please enter grade ->
22
You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for "Done".
Please enter grade ->
33
You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for "Done".
Please enter grade ->
D
You have entered 4 grades
The grades you have entered are:
0.00
```

The final for loop should be changed from:

```
printf("You have entered %d grades \n", gradeNum + 1);
printf("The grades you have entered are:  \n");
    for (j=0; j <= i; j++)
        printf("%.2f ", gradeBook[j]);
                printf("\n \n");
```

to something like the following:

```
printf("You have entered %d grades \n", totalEntered);
printf("The grades you have entered are:  \n");
    for (j=0; j <= totalEntered; j++) {
        printf("%.2f ", gradeBook[j]);
        printf("\n \n");
    }
```

This still has a problem though.  gradeBook is never updated anywhere so it will always ouput '0.00'.  I am not sure how you want to store or present the data so I took the liberty of making a few modifications to your initial code below.  I kept things close in spirit to your original code to provide you with a stepping stone to get through this set of problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int intArray [15];
    int gradeNum;
    int gradeEntered;
    int totalEntered = 0;
    char ans;
    char input [15];
    float * gradeBook;
    char done = 'D';

    for(gradeNum = 0; gradeNum < 15; gradeNum++) {
        printf("You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for \"Done\".");
        printf("\nPlease enter grade -> \n");
        fgets(input, 15, stdin);

        if(strncmp(input,&done,1)== 0) {
            break;
        }
        gradeEntered = atoi(input);

        intArray[gradeNum]= gradeEntered;
        totalEntered++;
    }

    gradeBook = malloc (totalEntered * sizeof(float));

    for (i = 0; i < totalEntered; i++) {
        gradeBook[i] = (float) intArray[i] / 10.0;
    }

    printf("You have entered %d grades \n", totalEntered);
    printf("The grades you have entered are:  \n");

    for (i =0; i < totalEntered; i++) {
        printf("%.2f ", gradeBook[i]);
        printf("\n \n");
    }

    free(gradeBook);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is some output when it is run...

```
You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for "Done".
Please enter grade ->
901
You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for "Done".
Please enter grade ->
874
You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for "Done".
Please enter grade ->
773
You have a maximum of 14 grades that can be entered. If less, then enter 'D' for "Done".
Please enter grade ->
D
You have entered 3 grades
The grades you have entered are:
90.10

87.40

77.30
```

If there is something you don't understand or want different, please let us know. Good Luck!

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel Added and thanks for the tip.  =)

Comment: --Thank you so very much! I will be making adjustments based on your suggestions. I greatly appreciate your breakdowns and explanations in each section. Although I am still learning, piece by piece as I am sure most of you did as well. I know that this is not learned overnight. Thanks again.